# Does $ab = b^2 \implies a=b? $

Tags: equivalence-relations

My textbook says that the follow is **not** true: $ab = b^2 \implies a=b $

However, I cannot find a single case where its not true.

What am I missing? Is it true or false? How do I go about proving these things?

Comment: Generally, its not true but in real numbers it is true.True to prove this for matrices

Comment: @AsharTafhim What do you mean by 'Generally its not true'?

Comment: It's true for $\mathbb R-\{0\}$...

Answer (score 2):

$5 * 0 = 0 * 0$ but $5 \neq 0$.

In general, you need cancellation for that property to hold. Cancellation is a property that allows one to derive the fact that

$$
ab = ac \implies b = c
$$

One example is $\mathbb Z - \{0\}$.

Comment: Cancellation is not equivalent to existence of inverses.

Comment: Apologies, mixed the two up. $\mathbb Z$ is a perfect example of the phenomenon :)

Comment: What about $\mathbb R-\{0\}$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb R - \{0\}$ is an example as well. It is stronger than $\mathbb Z - \{0\}$ since $\mathbb R$ has a notion of "inverses" that $\mathbb Z$ does not

Answer (score 1):

i would write $$ab=b^2$$ and this is equivalent to $$0=b(a-b)$$ thus we get $$a=b$$ or $$b=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Try $b=0$. Then $a\in\Bbb{R}\ni\{0\}$. So $a=0$ is not the unique solution and surely, $a$ not necessarily equals to $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $a=1$ and $b=0$. We see $ab = (1)(0) = 0 = 0^2 = b^2$ but $a \neq b$.